# How to loop through all directories in a drive using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have below powershell script which gives me permissions of one particular folder.

In below script, for example I can get the permissions of each folder (including sub folders) for Directory named SP,

How can I loop through all folders instead of specific targetDirectory?

```
$targetServer    = '\\tst-server\f$\'    #Enter hostname
$targetDirectory = 'SP' #Enter directory name
$target          = Join-Path -ChildPath $targetDirectory -Path $targetServer
$arrResults      = @() #Initialize array used to store custom object output
$exportPath      = 'C:\Users\adt\Desktop\Scripts\output\FolderPermission.csv' #Enter name of the CSV output file

#Query target directory for all 'folders' (excludes files via Where statement)
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $target | Where { $_.PSIsContainer } |
forEach {
    $objPath = $_.FullName
    $coLACL  = Get-Acl -Path $objPath
    forEach ( $objACL in $colACL ) {
        forEach ( $accessRight in $objACL.Access ) {
            $objResults = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
            $objResults | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name DirectoryPath      –Value $objPath
            $objResults | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Identity           –Value $accessRight.IdentityReference
            $objResults | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name SystemRights       –Value $accessRight.FileSystemRights
            $objResults | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name SystemRightsType   –Value $accessRight.AccessControlType
            $objResults | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IsInherited        -Value $accessRight.IsInherited
            $objResults | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InheritanceFlags   -Value $accessRight.InheritanceFlags
            $objResults | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name RulesProtected     –Value $objACL.AreAccessRulesProtected
            $arrResults += $objResults
        }
    }
}

$arrResults | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path $exportPath
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to set the `Path` to `F:`

```
Get-ChildItem F: -Recurse | Where { $_.PSIsContainer } | Foreach-Object { 
   #do something 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jisaak, let me give a try.

Comment: Just replace the two lines below the `#Query target directory for all ...` comment with the script I posted